# RouteParams and Query string

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to capture the query string, however I get error. The code I'm using is simple, however in the browser fails me.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    viewProviders: [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: '<p>the param is {{foo}}</p>'
})
export class app {
    constructor(params: RouteParams) {
            // http://local.../?myText=Hello    
            this.foo = params.get('myText');
        }
}
```

The [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html) is not very clear about this sort of thing. And it has absolutely nothing, just a `null`.

Comment: Are you using the deprecated-router package?

Comment: I'm not not using that package. I'm using the last package, is 2.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular RC1 Router, you need to have your component implement [*OnActivate*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b98c9e74e1ad73dc48eb67471ee91f4a1c01dfb6/modules/%40angular/router/src/interfaces.ts) interface to get the route parameters:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, OnActivate, RouteSegment } from '@angular/router';

Component({
    selector: 'body',
    providers: [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: '<p>the param is {{foo}}</p>'
})
export class app implements OnActivate {
    constructor() { }

    routerOnActivate(currSegment: RouteSegment) {
        this.foo = currSegment.getParam('myText'),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to replace `viewProviders` with the `providers` or better is if you provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` at the time of bootstrap your app like this :-

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

may help you, if still you have any problem please update your question with error message or better if you provide any plunker.